# Pandas filter dataframe rows with a specific year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and it has a `Date` column. I want to create two new data frames. One which contains all of the rows from `df` where the year equals `some_year` and another data frame which contains all of the rows of `df` where the year does not equal `some_year`. I know you can do `df.ix['2000-1-1' : '2001-1-1']` but in order to get all of the rows which are not in 2000 requires creating 2 extra data frames and then concatenating/joining them.

Is there some way like this?

```
include = df[df.Date.year == year]
exclude = df[df['Date'].year != year]
```

This code doesn't work, but is there any similar sort of way?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use datetime accesor.

```
import datetime as dt
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

include = df[df['Date'].dt.year == year]
exclude = df[df['Date'].dt.year != year]
```

Comment: Hi Vaishali. When I try this, with `year` as an integer value, I get `TypeError: invalid type comparison`. What should the type of `year` be?

Comment: there is a bracket missing in line 2

Answer (score 14):

You can simplify it by inverting mask by `~` and for condition use [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with `int` for cast string `year`:

```
mask = df['Date'].dt.year == int(year)
include = df[mask]
exclude = df[~mask]
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael. I have the same comment as for the other answer. When I try this `mask = df.Date.dt.year == year` I get `TypeError: invalid type comparison` . My `year` variable is an int. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I have already done this. But I just tried again and I get the same error. When I do df.Date it prints out `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

Comment: x| I just realized. My `year` vairable is a string not and int. Sorry. I used an int year and now it works. Sorry.

Comment: I actually prefer int for year. I was just being stupid. anyways thanks for all the help.