# How to trim outliers in dates in python?

Tags: python, date, trim

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
0    2003-01-02
1    2015-10-31
2    2015-11-01
16   2015-11-02
33   2015-11-03
44   2015-11-04
```

and I want to trim the outliers in the dates. So in this example I want to delete the row with the date `2003-01-02`. Or in bigger data frames I want to delete the dates who do not lie in the interval where 95% or 99% lie. Is there a function who can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `quantile()` on [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) or [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html).

```
dates = [datetime.date(2003,1,2),
         datetime.date(2015,10,31),
         datetime.date(2015,11,1),
         datetime.date(2015,11,2),
         datetime.date(2015,11,3),
         datetime.date(2015,11,4)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': [pd.Timestamp(x) for x in dates]})
print(df)

qa = df['DATE'].quantile(0.1) #lower 10%
qb = df['DATE'].quantile(0.9) #higher 10%

print(qa, qb)

#remove outliers
xf = df[(df['DATE'] >= qa) & (df['DATE'] <= qb)]
print(xf)
```

The output is:

```
        DATE
0 2003-01-02
1 2015-10-31
2 2015-11-01
3 2015-11-02
4 2015-11-03
5 2015-11-04
2009-06-01 12:00:00 2015-11-03 12:00:00
        DATE
1 2015-10-31
2 2015-11-01
3 2015-11-02
4 2015-11-03
```

Comment: This was exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your column converted to datetime format:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

you can do:

```
include = df[df.dt.year > 2003]
print(include)

[out]:
1   2015-10-31
2   2015-11-01
3   2015-11-02
4   2015-11-03
5   2015-11-04
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878156/pandas-filter-dataframe-rows-with-a-specific-year)

... regarding to your answer (it's basically the same idea,... be creative my friend):

```
s = pd.Series(df)
s10 = s.quantile(.10)
s90 = s.quantile(.90)

my_filtered_data = df[df.dt.year >= s10.year]
my_filtered_data = my_filtered_data[my_filtered_data.dt.year <= s90.year]
```

Comment: Yeah.. but I'd rather have a program that identify the outliers and the interval where for example 95 oder 99% of the dates lie. I heard of a method that call "trim" but don't find how it works