# function to run regression model to predict revenue based on multiple condiitons

Tags: python, function, regression, finance, revenue

I have to create a function that will simaltenously split my dataframe into test and train sets and then run the simplest regression model and return RMSE as a result. The task is to predict the revenue column by id and year.

I am quite new to this and I am stuck at the part where I have to split test and train sets, and figuring out how to join everything together.

Required split:

- train: all from 2021
- test: the rest of the years

Data example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022],
                   'id': [3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'price': [12, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                   'age': [20, 30, 30, 44, 31],
                   'product': [book, toy, book, tv, book],
                   'quantity': [2,1,2,5,9})
```

my code so far:

```
df['revenue'] = df.price*df.quantity
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year 

#this creates extra variables and puts them the way I need it 
def table(df):
   df2 = (df.groupby(['year','id'])
            .agg(revenue = ('revenue', 'sum'), 
                 age = ('age', 'unique'),
                 product_year_before = ('product', 'nunique'),
                 revenue_year_before =('revenue','sum')))
   s = df2['product_year_before'].rename(lambda x: x + 1, level=0)
   df2 = df2.drop('product_year_before',axis=1).join(s)
   s2 = df3['revenue_year_before'].rename(lambda x: x + 1, level=0)
   return df3= df3.drop('revenye_year_before',axis=1).join(s2)
table_result = table(df)                      
table(df)
```

**Question 1:**
I tried to split this way, but I get an error "only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [int]". Is there a way to fix this?

```
   test = df3[df3['year'].isin(2018)] 
   train = df3[~df3['year'].isin(2018)]
```

**Question 2:** How do I incorporate linear regression model to predict "revenue" column to the above function if my results need to be this:

```
MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y_actual,y_predicted)).mean() 
RMSE = math.sqrt(MSE)
return RMSE
```

Comment: Does [Pandas filter dataframe rows with a specific year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878156/pandas-filter-dataframe-rows-with-a-specific-year) answer your question?

Comment: Please limit your questions to one question.

Comment: What is the purpose of `df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year`? Isn't `df['year'] already numeric?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**:

As the error message states, `.isin()` requires a list, e.g. a list of years such as `[2017, 2018, 2020]`. You only pass an integer `2018`. What you can do is:

```
test = df[df['year'] == 2018] 
train = df[df['year'] != 2018]
```

... or whatever year you actually want in your test data.

**Question 2**:

Not entirely sure what you mean, but you could use `scikit-learn`'s [LinearRegression function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).
Use `reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)` to fit your regression, where `y` is your `revenue` column and `X` are your predictors. `Scikit-learn` also has a [function for RMSE calculation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html).
Together, use something like:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

Xtrain = train.drop('revenue', axis = 1).values
ytrain = train.revenue.values.ravel()
Xtest = test.drop('revenue', axis = 1).values
ytest = test.revenue.values.ravel()

reg = LinearRegression().fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
ypred = reg.predict(Xtest)
RMSE = mean_squared_error(ytest, ypred, squared = False)
```