# how can i clean part of a data set that contains data from before 2000?

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory

im new to python and to working with datasets, i'm using a data set that has certain stocks and stuff about them since the 1980's till the late 2010's, i dont want to use any of the stocks in the data set when i use the knn prediction, what can i do?

```
for i in df["Date"]:
  if(i.startswith("19")):
    f=df.drop(['Adj Close','Volume','High','Date','Low','Open', 'Close'], axis=1)
```

then i just get a copy of an empy dataset

```
print(f)
```

Empty DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you put the date as an index :

```
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
```

and then slice using this method (please put your dates)

```
df.loc['2000-01-01':'2020-02-01']
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not the best solution to iterate through rows in pandas datasets. The best way is using a mask, in your case:

```
f = df[df["Date"].gt("2000-01-01")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the below code works?

```
data[data['Date'] > "2000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what other posters said, you can filter by the date. The first thing you need to know is what format that column is in.

Try
`print(df.dtypes)`

if it's a datetime, you can then do

```
df = df[df['Date'].dt.year >= 2000]
```

This will result in assigning to df only the segments where the year is at least 2000.

If it isn't already a datetime, you can [change it to datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878156/pandas-filter-dataframe-rows-with-a-specific-year)